# Настройка проиндексированных линков при переносе с dle на wordpress в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, php, wordpress, dle

Друзья, подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно настроить .htaccess?
Перенёс данные с dle на wordpress, теперь ломаю голову, как правильно перенести линки, чтоб не потерять проиндексированные поисковиками данные.

У меня сейчас странички типа `index.php?newsid=2025` на dle,
а на wordpress странички вида `?p=2025`.
Соответственно, мне нужно, чтоб "`index.php?newsid=`" менялось на "`?p=`",
а точнее не менялось, а как бы внутри при вызове ссылки `index.php?newsid=2025` тянулся контент с `?p=2025`, то есть в браузере ссылка фактически не должна поменяться.